# Do the strings accessible via global variable `environ` not reflect any change to the environment?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, exec, api

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436631/674

> the file `/proc/$$/environ` ... does not reflect any changes to the environment, but just reports what the program received when it was `exec`ed by the process.

From APUE:

> Each  program  is  also  passed  an environment  list. Like  the 
>   argument  list,  the environment  list  is  an  array  of  character 
>   pointers,  with  each  pointer  containing  the address of a
>   null-terminated C string. The address of the array of pointers is
>   contained in the global variable `environ`:
>
> ```
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> Access to  speciﬁc  environment  variables  is  normally  through  the
>   `getenv` and `putenv` functions,  described  in  Section  7.9, 
>   instead  of  through  the environ variable.  But to go through the
>   entire environment, the `environ` pointer must be used.

Are `/proc/$$/environ` and the global variable `environ`   independent from each other or consistent with each other?

Do the strings accessed via `environ` also  not reflect any changes to the environment, but just reports the environment received by   `execve()`?

Or do the strings accessed via `environ` always reflect any change to them, just like that `getenv` always get the up-to-date environment strings?

Do the strings accessed via  `getenv` always reflect any change and are always up-to-date?

Thanks.

Comment: This ground has already been covered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302948/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/$$/environ` and the variable `environ` are independent. `environ` does reflect changes to the environment, and in fact the value of the pointer in `environ` also changes when environment variables are added to the environment via `putenv()` (but this is an implementation detail.)

We'll have to distinguish between the system call level, and the library level. At the system call level, the only mechanism related to the environment is the `envp` argument to the `execve` call. This parameter is expected to contain `name=value` pairs that make up the environment of the new program. This environment is copied to the stack of the new process, where the user space startup code can pick it up.

At the library level, we have

- the global variable `environ`, which points to a copy of the environment
- the functions `getenv()` and `putenv()` for examining and modifying the environment
- the `exec*` family of functions (not inlcuding `execve`) which either implicitly (via `environ`) or explicitly (passed via a parameter) access the environment

The `exec*` library functions ultimately call the `execve` system call. <strike>The `environ` variable does not point to the environment on the stack; instead the environment is copied to the process heap before the `environ` variable is set up (this is again an implementation detail.)</strike>

Why doesn't `/proc/$$/environ` reflect changes to the environment? `/proc/$$/environ` is a virtual file provided by the kernel, and the kernel has no way of knowing what is going on at this low level in the address space in a user process. The kernel has no knowledge of the `environ` variable, and is unaware of the data structures used by the process to store the environment.

Comment: Psst!  This is no longer the only mechanism at the system call level.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438007/5132 .

Comment: The link describes the `prctl()` system call with which you can, among other things, tell the kernel where in the process' memory the environment variables are stored, so `/proc/$$/environ` can reflect the updated environment. The process itself has to make the call. `prctl()` also assumes the variables are stored in the conventional way, and on the stack. But a process is free to do what it wants with the environment, including copying it to the heap, using a different data structure, etc. A shell might want to mix the environment with its internal (not yet exported) variables.

Comment: The last paragraph is kind of misleading -- the `/proc/PID/environ` really works by copying live stuff from the address space of the process. `/proc/PID/environ` will only stop reflecting the process' environment when the either the environment strings or the whole list (`char **environ`) has been relocated elsewhere. Just try it with a simple program like `int main(){ strcpy(getenv("PATH"), "/no/where"); poll(0, 0, -1); }` followed by `grep -z ^PATH /proc/PID/environ`.

Comment: @mosvy The relocation you mention happens very fast. Try changing an environment variable with `setenv()`, and you'll find the new string is allocated on the heap, and the change is not reflected by `/proc/PID/environ`. Or add a variable with `setenv()` and see how the variable `environ` now points to the heap. Yes, stuff is copied from the address space of the process, and you can poke new values to this array, but there is no guarantee that it is at all part of the data structures that libc uses to pass as the environment to a new process.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The kernel has all the ways of knowing what is going in the address space of a process -- it's just a matter of convenience how deep it goes. It's not like `/proc/PID/environ` is the original environment of a process (it _may_ reflect useland changes to it). There are also ways to make it point elsewhere (via `prctl(PR_SET_MM_ENV_START)`), or to implement it fully in userland (via `process_vm_readv()` or `/proc/PID/mem`). And the way `setenv()` works in glibc is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @mosvy The kernel knows the address space of a process, but it knows nothing about the logic of the program. Take a look at the figure on [this page](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/). `/proc/PID/environ` is a copy of the memory area marked `env` at the top of the figure. The `prctl` system call can be used to change the boundaries of this area, but this is very seldom done. The libc environment handling code does not use `prctl`. Instead libc allocates new memory on the heap for storing new and changed variables. `/proc/PID/environ` still returns the same area as before, i.e. the stale values