# How to change /proc/*/environ of a bash shell

Tags: bash, environment-variables, proc

This is the shell's PID:

```
nathan@guixlaptop ~ $ $$
bash: 10984: command not found
```

I export an environment variable:

```
nathan@guixlaptop ~ $ export TESTVAR=test
```

The variable is not found in the shell's environment:

```
nathan@guixlaptop ~ $ cat /proc/10984/environ | grep TESTVAR || echo "fail"
fail
```

How do I make the variable appear in environ?

Comment: What is the purpose of your question? Is there a reason  you wanted to see this variable in `/proc/PID/environ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to deal with the NUL-separated strings, and restart the shell to see the result you're looking for:

```
$ $$
bash: 9166: command not found 
$ export TESTVAR=test_question 

# at this point, you can check `/proc/9166/environ`, but `TESTVAR` won't show up until the shell is re-started 

$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/9166/environ
SHELL=/bin/bash
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
PWD=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
# ... etc, etc - the env var TESTVAR is not there... 

$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/9166/environ | grep TESTVAR
$

# re-start bash & try again:

$ exec bash 

$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/9166/environ | grep TESTVAR
TESTVAR=test_question
$
```

Attribution to @aviro & @stephenkitt for the simplifications (see comments)

Comment: You're making it more complicated than it should be. `cat /proc/PID/environ | tr '\0' '\n'` is much easier.

Comment: @aviro: Thanks - I saw your comment to the Q; no doubt `tr` is more efficient, but for me `awk` was *easier* 'cos I don't use `tr` often.

Comment: You don’t even need `cat` (or `less` — take care with `lesspipe` & co. if you’re used to piping `less` into other programs): `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/PID/environ` works just as well.

Comment: @StephenKitt: You're correct & thanks for the improvement! I used `less` b/c I wanted to see it myself before posting an answer.

Answer (score 8):

[`/proc/.../environ` contains the process’ initial environment](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> This file contains the initial environment that was set when the currently executing program was started via [`execve(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).
>
> ...
> If, after an [`execve(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), the process modifies its environment (e.g., by calling functions such as [`putenv(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) or modifying the [`environ(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) variable directly), this file will not reflect those changes.

To see changes, you need to start a new shell:

```
$ TESTVAR=test bash
$ grep TESTVAR /proc/$$/environ
grep: /proc/1825425/environ: binary file matches
```

You can’t change the contents shown in a running shell’s `environ`, unless you resort to invasive maneuvers; see [change /proc/PID/environ after process start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/302948/86440) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Another examples,you can use `strings` show proc/$$/environ file.

```
strings /proc/$$/environ  # $$ mean current process PID,
                            # strings process newline characters in file.
strings /proc/$$/environ | grep USER
export TESTVAR=123
env |grep TSETVAR  # found
strings /proc/$$/environ | grep TESTVAR # not found

# new session
bash
strings /proc/$$/environ | grep TESTVAR # found
```